# Possible condition on locally Euclidean subsets of Euclidean space to be embedded submanifold

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

Consider a (locally closed if needed) locally Euclidean subset $X\subset \mathbb R^n$. Given a point $p\in X$, let $\dim_pX$ denote the dimension of $X$ at $p$ and consider the following condition:

- There are *differentiable/smooth* germs of paths in $X$ based at $p$ whose tangents at $p$ span a space of dimension $\dim_pX$.

I am hopeful this condition may express that $X\subset\mathbb R^n$ is smooth at $p$ by asserting it has a tangent space with the correct dimension.

If all points of a (locally closed if needed) locally Euclidean subset  $X\subset\mathbb R^n$ satisfy the above condition, is $X\subset\mathbb R^n$ an embedded submanifold? Does this characterize submanifolds embedded in Euclidean space?

The question is motivated by thinking of manifolds as "things with tangent spaces".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a counterexample.  Define $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ by $f(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)=\sqrt[3]{r}\sin 2\theta$ and let $X\subset\mathbb{R}^3$ be the graph of $f$.  Since $f$ is continuous, $X$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and a topological surface.  Since $f$ is smooth away from the origin, $X$ is smooth away from the origin.  Moreover, the smooth paths $t\mapsto(t,0,0)$ and $t\mapsto(0,t,0)$ are contained in $X$ and have linearly independent tangents at the origin.  However, $X$ is not smooth at the origin because $f$ is not smooth at the origin.

In fact, you can even arrange for there to be smooth curves whose set of tangents at the origin *is* an entire plane, rather than just spanning one.  For instance, if you take $f(x,y)=\frac{x^3y}{x^4+y^2}$ (and $f(0,0)=0$), then $f$ is smooth away from the origin, is smooth when restricted to each line through the origin, and all its directional derivatives at the origin are $0$, but $f$ is not differentiable at the origin.  The graph of $f$ will then not be a smooth submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^3$, but at the origin it will have an entire "tangent plane" worth of smooth paths through the origin, namely all the lines through the origin.  (This example is taken from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/775262/86856).)

Comment: What I meant to ask was for a "tangent plane worth of smooth paths". I had in mind a picture similar to your first example but for some reason forgot about it when I wrote the question. The second example is very instructive. I asked a follow-up [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2606344/223002). Maybe this time it will be enough :)